# 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code' error in django project

Tags: django

I am getting this error in my django project, how can i resolve it.

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
/home/vishakha/webapps/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
            response = self.apply_response_fixes(request, response) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/vishakha/webapps/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in apply_response_fixes
            response = func(request, response) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/vishakha/webapps/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/utils.py in conditional_content_removal
    if 100 <= response.status_code < 200 or response.status_code in (204, 304): ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Test for `'status_code'` key existence before accessing it or catch and handle the error yourself.

Comment: You need to put in more effort to explain your question!
FWIW, naming a view function `test` causes this error in my app. I have no idea why... I can't find any name collisions although that would be my first guess. (I have no idea if you did that, but it might help!)

Answer (score 15):

Looks like you are not returning a instance of HttpResponse from your view. could you paste a code snippet? also, please try to unfold a highlighted exception (it's coloured with a dark grey background) and see what's the value of 'response' variable.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, @toudi is right. I am in such situation and now I do:

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

return JsonResponse({'success':False, 'errorMsg':errorMsg})
```

When you process the json part in jQuery, do:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(returned, status, xhr) {
        var result = returned['success']; // this will be translated into 'true' in JS, not 'True' as string
        if (result) { 
            ...
        else {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show your view; I suspect that you are simply returning the dict from your view, whereas you should be returning an HttpResponse.

if view returns serializable dict, you may have to convert it into JsonResponse